# Multiple Mosquitto brokers to exchange data between devices

Tags: ip, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I have 3 devices each of them have **Mosquitto broker** running on them. Each of this device has subscriber and publisher.

I am using IP of each device to open port at 8883 and exchange messages --> subscribe/publish their messages. If the case happens to be that devices use dynamic IP., How can I publish new IP-PORT address to its clients that are already connected? How to tackle this problem. Is my approach correct? Is there any other way I can create my own private IP-PORT address to the broker?

Answer (score 0):

Your broker needs to be reachable at a known location, be that fixed IP address or a DNS entry that points to it's current IP address.

Any clients connected at the time the IP address changes will be disconnected and will need to reconnect.

You've not said if these are all on the same LAN or spread across the internet, but either way you need some sort of dynamic DNS solution.

If the devices are all on the same LAN then you can use Avahi/mDNS/Bonjour to discover the current address of the device in the `.local` domain. Each broker will need to have a unique name.

If you are in a none lan environment then you will need to use a proper Dynamic DNS solution and have each broker have a unique fully qualified DNS name that the host machine can update when ever it's IP address changes.

Both of these solutions are more network admin solutions than programming questions so I suggest you ask on SuperUser if you have follow up questions.

There is a 3rd option, which is to have a 4th broker on a fixed IP address that acts as a central bridge for all the other brokers.